# problem with super.paintComponent(g)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics

This is the snippet :

```
protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {

 Runnable r=new Runnable() {

 @Override

  public void run() {
   while(true) {
     super.paintComponent(g);  // <----- line of error
     g.setColor(Color.red);
     g.drawOval(x,y,width,height);
     g.fillOval(x,y,width,height);
     x++;
     y++;
     width++;
     height++;
       if(width==20)
          break;
     try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
     } catch(Exception exc) {
         System.out.println(exc);
       }
   }
  }
};
 Thread moveIt=new Thread(r);
 moveIt.start();
}
```

The following error is produced when i compile the complete code :

```
d:\UnderTest>javac mainClass.java
mainClass.java:18: cannot find symbol
     super.paintComponent(g);
          ^
symbol:   method paintComponent(Graphics)
location: class Object
1 error
```

### **Why do i get this error?**

*In case this is my complete code :*

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.Thread;

class movingObjects extends JPanel {
int x=2,y=2,width=10,height=10;

@Override

protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {

Runnable r=new Runnable() {

 @Override

  public void run() {
   while(true) {
     super.paintComponent(g);
     g.setColor(Color.red);
     g.drawOval(x,y,width,height);
     g.fillOval(x,y,width,height);
     x++;
     y++;
     width++;
     height++;
       if(width==20)
          break;
     try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
     } catch(Exception exc) {
         System.out.println(exc);
       }
   }
  }
 };
   Thread moveIt=new Thread(r);
    moveIt.start();
    }
   }

class mainClass {

 mainClass() {
 buildGUI();
}

 public void buildGUI() {
 JFrame fr=new JFrame("Moving Objects");
 movingObjects mO=new movingObjects();
 fr.add(mO);
 fr.setVisible(true);
 fr.setSize(400,400); 
 fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

 public static void main(String args[]) {
  new mainClass();
  }
 }
```

Comment: Calling paintComponent from a different thread is bad news, by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a Qualified Super.

```
movingObjects.super.paintComponent(g);
```

Because, when you use `this` or `super` inside an inner class (in this case: `Runnable`), you will get the innerclass. If you want to use the outer class from the inner class, use a [Qualified This](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.8.4) or a Qualified Super.

```
YourOuterClassName.this
YourOuterClassName.super
```

Qualified Super is a term I can't find in the JLS, I invented it by myself.

Comment: This may technically answer the question about why the code doesn't compile, but it should NOT be considered a solution to your painting problem.

Comment: That is because of you never updated the screen. Try to make a call like `movingObjects.super.update(g);` it is definitely not the correct way to do so. If you want to learn a proper way, you should learn more about Swing. Observing a game-engine is very interesting. Personally, I like this one from Ivo Wetzel: https://github.com/BonsaiDen/Bonsai-Game-Library

Comment: Never call update(g). That is old code used for AWT applications and should not be used for Swing. In Swing you use repaint() to tell the component to repaint itself.

Comment: continuous exceptions when i used `movingObjects.super.update(g);` !

Answer (score 5):

If you want animation on a Swing panel then use a [Swing Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

You should not use a while (true) loop and that code should definitely not be a part of the paintComponent() method or invoke the paintComponent() method directly.

In you custom panel you need to set properties like setOvalLocation(Point). Then when the Timer fires you update the oval location and invokd repaint on the panel.

I suggest you start by reading the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/refining.html) for a more detailed explanation and example.

Comment: The answer is too complex to go into detail here. Properties of a component should be updated on the Event Dispatch Thread. Check the Table of Contents from the links I've given you above and read the section on "Currency" for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Because `Runnable` has no `paintComponent()` method. This is one of the drawbacks of using anonymous inner classes, it makes it hard to see what the current context is, but in your case, the context is the `run()` method, therefore `super` refers to the superclass of your anonymous inner class, which is `Runnable`.

If you want to refer to the superclass of the outer class from an inner class, you should use `movingObjects.super.paintComponent()`

Comment: See the answer of @camickr on that one. `paintComponent()` is probably not the method you need to override at all, in fact you don't have to do this thread starting business at all.