# using repaint() method in this code

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics

I am having a problem using the repaint method in the following code.Please suggest how to use repaint method so that my screen is updated for a small animation.
This is my code :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class movingObjects extends JPanel {
   Timer timer;
   int x = 2, y = 2, width = 10, height = 10;

   public void paintComponent(final Graphics g) { // <---- using repaint method
      ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.drawOval(x, y, width, height);
            g.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
            x++;
            y++;
            width++;
            height++;
         }
      };
      new Timer(100, taskPerformer).start();
   }
}

class mainClass {
   mainClass() {
      buildGUI();
   }

   public void buildGUI() {
      JFrame fr = new JFrame("Moving Objects");
      movingObjects obj = new movingObjects();
      fr.add(obj);
      fr.setVisible(true);
      fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      fr.setSize(1300, 700);
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      new mainClass();
   }
}
```

Comment: I've never seen an ActionListener created in a paintComponent method before. You get points for creativity, but not for functionality. Get that out of the paintComponent method.

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels can you tell the reason behind ?

Comment: You where given the answer to this question 2 days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228775/problem-with-super-paintcomponentg. Quit wasting our time and pay attention to the answers given. I told you NOT to have a loop in the paintComponent(). I gave you a link to the Swing tutorial that explained how to do painting and how to use Timers. Don't expect us to spoon feed code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to delay the actual painting.  The component needs to be painted when it is asked to be painted.

Instead, use your timer to modify some state in `MovingObjects`.  In your case the state you want to change is `x`, `y`, `width` and `height`. When your timer fires, increment those values and call `repaint()`.

Then in your `paintComponents` method, you would just use those values to paint the component

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  g.setColor(Color.red);
  g.drawOval(x,y,width,height);
  g.fillOval(x,y,width,height);
}
```

### Edit

Not sure what you're having trouble with, but calling repaint() is not difficult:

```
ActionListener taskPerformer=new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
      x++;
      y++;
      width++;
      height++;
      repaint();
   }
};
new Timer(100,taskPerformer).start();
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to call repaint here?

Comment: @Suhail: Just call repaint from your Swing Timer.

Comment: @ Mark Peters I am unable to do it.Can you please elaborate the code in your answer. ( with repaint() )

Comment: @Suhail: I updated your answer, though I'm not sure what you're having trouble with.  If you still cannot get it to work, you need to work harder at describing your problem.  "I am unable to do it" is not informative.

Comment: @ Mark Peter Thank you for the update,but how do i invoke the action listener?

Comment: @Suhail: You could put that code in the constructor for `movingObjects`.  The `ActionListener` is invoked by the `Timer` being triggered.

Comment: Read the Timer API to find out how to stop it!